# @EnableBatchProcessing breaks other JPA junit tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, junit5

I have a microservice where multiple @DataJpaIntegrationTest junit tests are present. As soon as I am adding @EnableBatchProcessing , all junits annotated with @DataJpaIntegrationTest are failing.

Problem seem to be as no transaction is happening.

I am using custom batch configurer to use Map based JobRepository utilizing Resourceless transactionManager.

@DataJpaIntegrationTest looks as below:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.cloud.stream.function.definition="
})
public @interface DataJpaIntegrationTest {
}
```

Let me know if further details are required

I got the root cause of the problem but unaware of the solution.
As soon as I removed custom batch configurer , everything started working fine.

However, @DataJpaTest is still failing with below reason

```
"eventSource":"org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer","message":"No transaction manager was provided, using a DataSourceTransactionManager"
```

**How can I have the jpa transaction intact while using map based repository.**

Comment: Have you had any dice with this, I am haping the same problem, inserts being delayed and unit tests failing?

Comment: @Jim I don't remember clearly but when I could not find any concrete solution , i moved to testcontainers instead of in-memory db